# PS Mongodb Mdbc - Get-MdbcData -Count returns 0 Value

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am new to MongoDB - I have a simple script like so:

```
Connect-Mdbc -ConnectionString mongodb://localhost:27018 -DatabaseName Local -CollectionName Media
#
$LASTEXITCODE
$Collection
$Database
#
Write-Host $Collection.CollectionNamespace
Write-Host $Database.DatabaseNamespace
#

#
Get-MdbcData -Count # Should read 43903 but gives 0
```

output is as follows:

```
CollectionNamespace : Local.Media
Database            : MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl
DocumentSerializer  : MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer
Indexes             : 
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1+MongoIndexManager[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]
Settings            : AssignIdOnInsert=True;GuidRepresentation=Standard;ReadConcern={ 
};ReadEncoding=null;ReadPreference={ 
                  Mode : Primary };WriteConcern={ };WriteEncoding=null

Client            : MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient
DatabaseNamespace : Local
Settings          : GuidRepresentation=Standard;ReadConcern={ };ReadEncoding=null;ReadPreference={ 
Mode : Primary 
                };WriteConcern={ };WriteEncoding=null

Local.Media
Local
0
```

Using Compass I can see that there are 43903 documents in the collection "Media" yet the -count parameter on `Get-MdbcData returns 0.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can shed light on why this is happening?

Keith

Comment: are you sure your port is 27018 - that is not standard.  The standard port is 27017.

Comment: Yes the port is correct. I am able to connect to the database, list the collection "Media" and yet when I issue any other Mdbc cmdlet I get zero records returned. many thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I'd say, I cannot reproduce. Double check your connection string and database and collection names (mind they are case sensitive).

Comment: Its worth noting - mongodb will not raise an error if you reference a non existing database or collection.  If you try to get count on a non-existing collection you will get a value of zero.

Comment: Whoah Barry thank you. Case sensitivity Local should be local. So sorry for making a fuss and thank  you too Roman for taking the trouble to help me out.